# android keyboard multi-character key

Tags: android, keyboard

How do I specify that I want a key press to do more that 1 character?   Like () or a smiley?  More specifically, for my problem, how do I do this using the popupKeyboard?  I want the user to be able to choose a selection and have that selections image and result be multi-character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only using a standard example of a popupKeyboard xml file. Appears you can put anything you want in it, just like the xml file you are using to define your main keyboard (the one from which the popup originated). You can use a different xml per key. In those xmls you can make the keylabel some multi-character text and a) use a keyCode value as some code your keyboard doesn't use. Then when you see that keycode show up in your app, replace it with the multicharacter text you want. or b) use keyOutputText and just put that as the same as your keyLabel. I will post this as the answer once 8 hours has elapsed and it allows me to self-answer.